# Is it possible to use plain CSS instead of SASS in Jekyll

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I want to create a simple Jekyll site and I need none of the features of SASS.

I searched the docs but found no answer.

Comment: you can write plain CSS using sass, after all CSS is SASS

Comment: Sure, but still, I'd feel better if I knew that my CSS wouldn't go through processing.

Comment: maybe try to consider CSS file as static and work with them like image for example, You include them directly on you HTML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

- Just use the scss extension for your css (css is a subset of scss).
  As stated in the documentation https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/ Jekyll will
  take care of them
- create a directory css, put your css there and refrence to it from your files. 
  Jekyll will copy it verbatim to the generated site (documentation reference:   https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/ other file/folder section)
- put your css files in an external url (a cdn, maybe?) and reference them in your files.

I would go with the first option, but if you are not at ease with Jekyll manipulating your css files, and if you are really picky with it copying is still a form of manipulation, you may resort to the other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I would not go for option 1, but for option 2 (create a CSS directory). I hate it when my inspect debugger does not show me the right line numbers. Option 3 does not seem very logical to me.

Comment: @JoostS The options are in order of usefulness, for me. You can still address the issue you have with the first one with [sourcemap support](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass) , but this shoud belong to another question/answer imho